# Prob. 4, Sec. 4.3, in Kreyszig's Functional Analysis textbook: Application of the Hahn Banach Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

Here is Prob. 4, Sec. 4.3, in the book *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications* by Erwine Kreyszig:

> Let $X$ be a (real or complex) vector space, and let $p \colon X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function satisfying $$p(x+y) \leq p(x) + p(y) \ \mbox{ for all } \ x, y \in X$$ and $$p(\alpha x) = \lvert \alpha \rvert p(x) \ \mbox{ for all } x \in X \mbox{ and for all scalars } \alpha.$$ Let $x_0$ be a point of $X$. Then (how to show that?) there is a linear functional $\tilde{f}$ on $X$ such that $\tilde{f}(x_0) = p(x_0)$ and $\left\lvert \tilde{f}(x) \right\rvert \leq p(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

First of all, here is the (generalized) Hahn Banach Theorem for (real or complex) vector spaces.

> Let $X$ be a real or complex vector space; let $Z$ be a subspace of $X$; let $p \colon X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $$p(x+y) \leq p(x) + p(y) \ \mbox{ for all } x, y \in X$$ and $$p(\alpha x ) = \lvert \alpha \rvert p(x) \ \mbox{ for all } x \in X \mbox{ and for all scalars } \alpha;$$ and let $f$ be a linear functional defined on $Z$ such that $$\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq p(x) \ \mbox{ for all }  x \in Z.$$ Then there is a linear functional $\tilde{f}$ defined on all of  $X$ such that $$\tilde{f}(x) = f(x) \ \mbox{ for all } x \in Z$$ and $$\left\lvert \tilde{f}(x) \right\rvert \leq p(x) \ \mbox{ for all } x \in X.$$

This is Theorem 4.3-1 in the book  *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications* by Erwine Kreyszig.

My effort:

> Let $Z$ be the subspace of $X$ spanned by $x_0$, and let the functional  $f$ be defined on $Z$ by $$f(\alpha x_0) = \alpha p(x_0) \mbox{ for all scalars } \alpha .$$

> We can show that $p(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in X$, and $f$ satisfies all the conditions in the hypothesis of the above theorem. So there is a linear functional $\tilde{f}$ on $X$ such that $\tilde{f}(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in Z$ and $\left\lvert \tilde{f}(x) \right\rvert \leq p(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

> Thus, $\tilde{f}(\alpha x_0) = \alpha p(x_0)$ for all scalars $\alpha$ and hence $\tilde{f}(x_0) = p(x_0)$.

Is this proof correct and clear enough in each and every detail? Or, are there any issues therein of accuracy or clarity?